# convert spring integration beans to java config

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-integration

I am using spring integration for ftp integration. Following is my config

```
<int:channel id="ftpChannel"/>

    <int-ftp:outbound-channel-adapter  id="ftpOutbound"
                channel="ftpChannel"
                remote-directory="/"
                session-factory="ftpClientFactory">
        <int-ftp:request-handler-advice-chain>
            <int:retry-advice />
        </int-ftp:request-handler-advice-chain>
    </int-ftp:outbound-channel-adapter>
```

How do I convert this to java based spring configuration?

Answer (score 2):

From one side, please, pay attention that we have already Spring Integration Java DSL project and you can find there the FTP [test-cases](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/dsl/test/ftp/FtpTests.java) to figure out how to configure the FTP adapter from Java and DSL perspective.

From other side you should take a look to the Spring Integration Reference Manual, Annotation Configuration [chapter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/configuration.html#annotations) to figure out what is `@ServiceActivator`, `@Transformer` and others. Your particular case may look like:

```
@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "ftpChannel", adviceChain = "retryAdvice")
public MessageHandler ftpHandler() {
    FileTransferringMessageHandler handler = new FileTransferringMessageHandler(this.ftpClientFactory);
    handler.setRemoteDirectoryExpression(new LiteralExpression("/"))
    return handler;
}
```

and so on.
The `retryAdvice` in my sample is bean name for the `RequestHandlerRetryAdvice`.

Comment: What is your recommendation?

Comment: Thanks for help but this does not really solve my problem. Can you elaborate a bit more? the annotation configuration chapter is a bit complicated for me to understand at this point.

Comment: Actually, the only Java & Annotation configuration is really complicated and it doesn't depend from that documentation. Especially you shouldn't forget to add `@EnableIntegration` alongside with the `@Configuration` and so on. From other side maybe Java DSL would be simpler for you...